# Using sed editor to replace a string containing backslash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command, ubuntu-14.04

How can i use the sed to replace string containing backslash "\" is all files of specific directory.

I tried this but wont work for me

```
find /home/tds/nfb -type f -exec sed -i 's//var/www/tds///home/tds//' {} \;
```

I want to replace "/var/www/tds/" with "/home/tds/"

Comment: Are you trying to replace a backslash `\ ` or a forward slash `/`? Your text says one but your example the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
find /home/tds/nfb -type f -exec sed -i 's|/var/www/tds/|/home/tds/|' {} \;
```

where the delimiter `/` is replaced by `|`.  (sed can use almost any character as a delimiter -- it picks whatever character follows the `s`).   Alternatively, you could escape all your backslashes as follows and still used `\`:

```
sed -i 's/\/var\/www\/tds\//\/home\/tds\//'
```